# Can't execute msg (and other) Windows commands via subprocess

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess

I have been having some problems with `subprocess.call()`, `subprocess.run()`, `subprocess.Popen()`, `os.system()`, (and other functions to run command prompt commands) as I can't seem to get the `msg` command to work.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("msg * Hey",shell=True)
```

In theory, this should send "Hey" to every computer on the network unfortunately, this isn't running at all and I'm not quite sure why. I can run it on `cmd` successfully, but can't get it to work from Python.

I'd love to hear why this doesn't work and hopeful a way to fix my code or an alternate solution.

**Edit:** Solved, thanks for everyone's help. Upgrading to 64-bit Python did the trick.

Comment: `msg *` sends a message to every session on the specified server (by default, the computer you're issuing the command on), not to every computer on the network. If you're expecting it to send a message to every computer on the network, that's probably why it's not.

Comment: @ErykSun: You should post your comment as an answer — solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

In 64-bit Windows, "msg.exe" is only distributed as a native 64-bit binary. This file won't be found if you're using 32-bit Python, which executes under WOW64 emulation. WOW64 redirects "System32" access to the "SysWOW64" directory. In Windows 7+, use the virtual "SysNative" directory to access the real "System32". For example:

```
sysroot = os.environ['SystemRoot']
sysnative = os.path.join(sysroot, 'SysNative')
if not os.path.exists(sysnative):
    sysnative = os.path.join(sysroot, 'System32')

msgexe_path = os.path.join(sysnative, 'msg.exe')
subprocess.call([msgexe_path, '*', 'Hey'])
```

Note that msg.exe has nothing to do with CMD, so there's no reason to use `shell=True`.

Answer (score -1):

Try calling it as separate arguments:

```
subprocess.call(['msg', '*', 'Hey'], shell=True)
```

Comment: While it's legal to pass a list of arguments with `shell=True` in later versions of Python, it works by trying to guess at how to reassemble the string you probably wanted, so you might as well just use that string instead of trying to second-guess how it guesses and work out a list that will get built into the string you wanted.

Comment: @abarnert, passing a list with `shell=True` is almost always wrong in POSIX because it passes the parameters to the shell instead of the program, e.g. `call(['/bin/echo \$0=$0 \$1=$1', 'a', 'b'], shell=True)`. In Windows it's wrong because `subprocess.list2cmdline` is written for `CommandLineToArgvW` and VC++ `argv` parsing, not the CMD shell's syntax. Do use a list with `shell=False` for the sake of cross-platform code. Most programs in Windows follows VC++ rules, so it should usually work.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the complete path of the `msg` command. Example as listed

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("/usr/local/bin/msg * Hey",shell=True)
```