# How to create an alert box without using Tkinter?

Tags: python, windows, alert, message, box

I need to create a message box in python without using python Tkinter library so that I can use that before using `exit()` function this will display the message and answer as soon as user presses okay, user gets out of program.

Comment: Windows has a [`msg`](https://www.lifewire.com/msg-command-2618093) command that a Python script could run (via `subprocess.run()` or `os.system()`) to do something like what you want.

Comment: okay thanks that may help

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with Windows' `msg` command. The code is based on @ErykSun's comment under the question [Can't execute msg (and other) Windows commands via subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651872/cant-execute-msg-and-other-windows-commands-via-subprocess).

```
import os
import subprocess

sysroot = os.environ['SystemRoot']
sysnative = (os.path.join(sysroot, 'SysNative')
                if os.path.exists(os.path.join(sysroot, 'SysNative'))
             else
                os.path.join(sysroot, 'System32'))
msgexe_path = os.path.join(sysnative, 'msg.exe')
subprocess.run([msgexe_path, '*', 'ALL YOUR BASE ARE WHERE BELONG TO US.'])
```